# Automatic text classification using n-gram model

Tags: data-mining, n-gram, text-classification

hi i'am a newbie to data mining. My task is to automatically classify text documents using n-grams method.

I could not find proper resources on this topic, kindly help me how to proceed in this topic, where can i find tutorials based on n-gram classification.

i need java source code on this topic for my understanding.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend  [Stanford's online NLP course](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfoudtpBV68&list=PL6397E4B26D00A269) by Dan Jurafsky & Chris Manning. Chapter 4 addresses n-grams, but all the chapters before it give a great background.

Stanford also has some great [open source software](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/index.shtml) you can use for text classification, from tokenizing to part of speech tagging.

Answer (score 2):

i found better tutorial with documentation in

http://textcat.sourceforge.net/README.txt

http://textcat.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html